# Retrieve specific string in php json_decode

Tags: php, json

How can I take **string(5)** from a nested array working with json in php, I have the following code:

```
$results = json_decode($response, TRUE);
var_dump($results);
```

and the output is:

```
array(8) { ["name"]=> string(9) "Remaining" ["count"]=> int(1) ["frequency"]=> string(8) "realtime"
["version"]=> int(2) ["newdata"]=> bool(false) ["lastrunstatus"]=> string(7) "success" ["lastsuccess"]=>
string(39) "Sat Apr 12 2014 01:04:30 GMT+0000 (UTC)" ["results"]=> array(1) { ["Calories"]=> array(1) {
[0]=> array(1) { ["calorias"]=> string(5) "2,860" } } } }
```

I need to take the **"2,860"** so I can encode it again in another array and echo it.
First time using PHP, I'm more used to python. Please help (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should serve your purpose:

```
$value = $results["results"]["Calories"][0]["calorias"];
```

Of course you may use any variable name of your choice instead of `$value`.